# No such table thrown, even if database contents records and in code use generated model

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

This code get records of `Contacts` from `ContactsDB.db`:

```
public async Task<List<Models.Contacts>> Read()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("ContactsDB.db");
        return _contacts = new List<Models.Contacts>(connection.Table<Models.Contacts>());
    });
}
```

This is model of the `Contacts` table that SQLite toolbox has generated:

```
public partial class Contacts
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [NotNull]
    public String ID { get; set; }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String PathToImage { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public Int64? IsFavorite { get; set; }
    public Int64? GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

[Screenshot of records from ContactsDB.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCXJW.png)

I have changed Build Action parameter of `ContactsDB` to `Content` but this does not change the situation. In my past this exception was thrown in situation when I wrote name of DB in connection string that not equal to DB name itself. At this time I make copy paste of DB name but exception throws yet.

And even with generated model and [SQLite](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) capacity I can not find reasons why exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the table name exactly matches the name of the table in the database using the `TableAttribute`:

```
[Table("NameOfYourTableInDb")]
public partial class Contacts
{
   ...
}
```

Also, I think you may be accidentally creating a new database inside your app data directory, which is probably not what you want if you are deploying a **read-only DB** with your project. To get the right path to the file, you will need the following

```
var appDb = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///ContactsDB.db"));
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(appDb.Path);
```

`ms-appx:///` points to the root of the application install directory.

However, if you **also need to modify** the data in the database, you will have to first copy the DB file to the application data directory:

```
StorageFile dbFile = null;
try
{
    dbFile = await ApplicationData.Current
       .LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ContactsDB.db");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //file does not exist
}
if (dbFile == null)
{
   //copy db deployed with app
   var appDb = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
       new Uri("ms-appx:///ContactsDB.db")); 
   dbFile = await appDb.CopyAsync(
       ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);     
}
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbFile.Path); 
                                                   //same as "ContactsDB.db"
```

In this case I am first checking if the DB was not copied already and in case it was not, I copy the read-only DB deployed with the app to the app's local storage, which is read-write. Note that I could also use `"ContactsDB.db"` as the connection string directly, because this will assume the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` working directory. For better clarity, however, I used `dbFile.Path`.

Comment: I have not exactly understood what `dbExists` variable do.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is just leftover from the original code, which I have then rewritten more succinctly